# How to remove a cell from tableView with animation through IBAction? iOS Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm building a todo-list app, and I'm holding a task model array and tableView in my view controller.

Each cell in this tableView contains several UI elements, one of them is a UIView that is actually a checkbox, implemented by Skyscanner's pod:
https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox

I would like to remove a cell when a user tap on the checkbox (with animation).

I set an IBAction to the UIView, I know which element in the array I want to remove (I tagged each UIView) but I cannot use the method

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

since I don't have the index path.
I want to find a nice way to remove the cell with an index, preferably without holding an indexPath variable (I tried that but not sure how to implement it correctly since cells can be removed from various indexes).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create the indexpath if you know the row and section and delete the row. Make sure to delete the item for the array before calling tableView.deleteRows

Comment: IndexPath is row and section if your have only one section and you have tagged your rows the you can recreate IndexPath easily

Comment: Just posted the answer, thanks both for helping out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that helped!
I'm answering my own question because it was a combination of your answers!

as Puneet Sharma, Reinier Melian and Yun CHEN said, I managed to create an index path inside the function.
Puneet's comment is very important, you **must** remove the element from the array **before** you remove the cell.

PS.
Maybe I could create the IndexPath way before I even asked the question, but in the line

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: checkbox.tag, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Xcode does not auto complete this initialization at all.

This is the code that remove the cell just like I wanted:

```
       @IBAction func completeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let checkbox = (sender as! M13Checkbox)
    self.tasks.remove(at: checkbox.tag)

    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: checkbox.tag, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Set the action event on the checkbox/Button like bellow in `cellForRowatIndexPath`. don't forgot to add the tag on every checkbox/Button.

```
cell.btnCounter.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btnCounter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You need to handle event as below

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Here sender.tag will give you the tapped checkbox/Button index from the cell
        your_array.remove(at: sender.tag) //Remove your element from array
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0))], with: .automatic) //Hope it is in section 0
    }
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

// Check this  snap code

```
@IBAction func  btnAction(_ sender : UIButton){

        // get Indexpath with Button position

         let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableview)
         let indexPath: IndexPath? = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        self.yourArrayDatasource.remove(at: indexPath.row)  // don't forget to replace your array of data source

        self.tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)


    }
```

I hope it help you